# Reporting 1099-? (takes place of 1099-G and 1099-INT) on tax return?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, amended-tax-return, form-1099

After filing my return, I received the following [tax form (sample)](http://www.tax.virginia.gov/Documents/2012%20-%201099G%20web%2011%2002%2012.pdf).  The form notes "THIS FORM TAKES THE PLACE OF FEDERAL FORMS 1099-G AND 1099-INT" but neither seems like G (unemployment) nor INT (interest).

On my form:

```
Box 1: $######.##
Box 2: $0.00
Box 3: 2012
```

How do I properly report this form?

If applicable, I used "H&R Block Free Edition" and am using it to amend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably the tax refund for the previous year (also reported on 1099-G). Look in the "Income" section of H&R Block where to write down the information about the state tax refunds.

Answer (score 2):

If you did not itemize your deductions in the previous year, and therefore did not receive a credit for the state taxes you were refunded, you do not need to declare the state refund as income in the subsequent year.

> If you did not itemize your deductions in the previous year, do not include the refund in income. If you deducted the taxes in the previous year, include all or part of the refund on Form 1040, line 10, in the year you receive the refund.

See [Pub 17](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch22.html#en_US_2012_publink1000173147).

Comment: H&R Block does that calculation. I suggest to enter it into the program and follow the guidance, that's why he's using it instead of just filling PDF's on his own to begin with.

Comment: @littleadv Never mind, misread the question disregard last comment, I didn't see that he had used the H&R Block for the original return as well.

Comment: (I think it's always good to double check the software, though, especially when any calculation involves the state component, as the software companies are notorious for throwing the state modules together at the last second)

Comment: true, but this particular part has nothing to do with any state component. Its part of the Federal tax calculations, which are usually tested much more meticulously (especially with regards to such a trivial thing as state refund and itemized deductions).